# Including static js files in django 1.7

Tags: javascript, django, zurb-foundation

Here is part of `settings.py`:

```
STATIC_URL = '/static/'

STATICFILES_DIRS = (
    os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static'),
)
```

HTML template:

```
{% load staticfiles %}
...
<head>
    <title>HelpDesk System</title>
    <script scr="{% static "js/vendor/jquery.js" %}" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="{% static "css/foundation.css" %}">
    <script scr="{% static "js/foundation.min.js" %}" type="text/javascript"></script>
</head>
<body>
<script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $(document).foundation();
    });
</script>
...
</body>
```

Static folder tree:

[image]

Result:

Css file loads as expected, but js does't and error occurs: `Can't find variable: $`

Comment: Are you using the development server to serve these static files? Are you getting a 404 for the `jquery.js` file or is it being loaded but just with an error? Have you checked that the `jquery.js` contents are actually correct?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It looks like your script tags contain the wrong attribute for specifying the source.

```
<script src="{% static "js/vendor/jquery.js" %}" type="text/javascript"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="{% static "css/foundation.css" %}">
<script src="{% static "js/foundation.min.js" %}" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

Comment: I've spend several hours trying to figure this out. Thanks a lot and damned html